# What is the difference between Core Reporting API and the new Real-Time Reporting API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

[Real-Time API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/)

[Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/)

Hey guys,

Would you mind explaining the difference between these? How would I actually use the new API to build a realtime dashboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anwser your first question:
Real-Time API lets you query information about whats happening on your sight right this minute.   But Dimensions and metrics you can select from this API is limited.    https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/

Core Reporting API the data is a bit older if my memory servies it takes them up to 4 hours to process hits and store them for use with the Core reporting api. But after processing there are a lot more dimensions and metrics available to you. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

Without knowing what language you are planing to use or how you are going to impliment its a bit hard to anwser your second question.  But you use the Real-Time API the same as you would use the Core-Reporting API.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the delay in processing, so they seemed nearly identical.